# includes/eager load associated models with graphql-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I've been searching for examples on how to translate a traditional ActiveRecod .includes for associated models, while using graphQL-ruby, and haven't found any. 
As a use case, let's say we have the following models:

```
User
has_many :books

Book
belongs_to :user
has_many :chapters

Chapter
belongs_to :book
has_many :pages

Page
belongs_to :chapter
```

How could we implement the following:

```
User.includes(books: {chapters: :pages})
```

The actual nested GraphQL query is relatively simple; however, it seems to be running at N+1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the new Lookahead feature in v1.9 could help with this. https://graphql-ruby.org/queries/lookahead.html

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a small gem for graphql-ruby that generates includes by walking a GraphQL Query.

https://github.com/thesquarefoot/graphql_includable

For your example you would call `User.includes_from_graphql(ctx)` in the User field resolver.

Comment: Note that this no longer works for the class based API for graphql. ctx.irep_node no longer gets passed through either, so a new solution is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use graphql-preload gem to preload associations in Graphql

https://github.com/ConsultingMD/graphql-preload